# Upper bound like $O(\log T)$ for the following sum of square root.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

I'm wondering if an upper bound in the order of $O(\log T)$ can be gotten for this sum:

$\sum_{t=1}^{T}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{d}\frac{a_j(t+1)-a_j(t)}{a_j^2(t)}}$,

where $d>0$ is a fixed integer, $a_j(t+1)\ge a_j(t)>1$, $\sum_j a_j(t+1)-a_j(t)\le 1$ and $\sum_j a_j(t)\le t+d$.

Comment: Random comments: Various constructions all seem to obey the $O(\log T)$ bound. WLOG we can take $a_j(1)=1$. The case $d=1$ already seems to contain the essential complexity. Setting $\delta(t) = a_1(t+1)-a_1(t) \le 1$, we see we want an upper bound for $$\frac{\sqrt{\delta_1}}1 + \frac{\sqrt{\delta_2}}{1+\delta_1} + \frac{\sqrt{\delta_3}}{1+\delta_1+\delta_2} + \cdots + \frac{\sqrt{\delta_T}}{1+\delta_1+\cdots+\delta_{T-1}}.$$ Some examination suggests that this function is increasing in each $\delta_t$, which would mean that the maximum is given by $a_1(t) = t$ which satisfies $O(\log T)$.

Comment: I find for $d = 1$, if $a(t+1)-a(t)=1/T$, $\sum_{t=1}^{T}\frac{\sqrt{1/T}}{a(1)+t/T} \ge \frac{\sqrt{T}}{a(1)+1}$. So essentially this sum is not upper bounded by $O(\log T)$.

Comment: For me is not clear what is the summation range for $j$ in $\sum_j  a_j(t)$. If it is unbounded, then, since  each $a_j(t)>1$, we have that $t+d$ is unbounded. If $j$ ranges from $1$ to $d$ and each $t\ge t_0>0$ then if we put $a_j(t)=1+\frac {t_0}{d}$ we assure that the sum to estimate is $0$ and all required for $a_j(t)$ conditions  hold.